# Oracle 12c ojdbc7 driver causing issues with result.getString("DATE_COLUMN")

Tags: oracle

We are in the process of upgrading to Oracle 12c and so are using the ojdbc7(12.1.0.2.0) driver.  However we noticed that while fetching a DATE column from a table using the resultSet.getString("DATE_COLUMN"), its now returning DayLight Saving adjusted time as well. Please note the DB is located in CST US timezone.

Say for e.g.

If the date in the column that was initially inserted was "2014-03-09 02:30:00" which is by the way the day when the daylight saving started in the US in 2014.

Here is the line of code used to fetch this value.

```
  String sql = "SELECT DATE_COLUMN FROM A_TABLE";
     ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery(sql);
     while (rs.next())
     {
        String dateString = rs.getString("DATE_COLUMN");
     }
```

Here are the results of this code snippet with the 2 different drivers.

odjbc6(11.2.0.3.0)  -  2014-03-09 **02:30:00**

ojdbc7(12.1.0.2.0)  -  2014-03-09 **03:30:00.0**

If you see the highlighted time fields, you can see that its now fetching 3:30:00.0 instead of 2:30 with the ojdbc7 driver, which suggests that the driver is getting the daylight savings adjusted time of the local timezone of the Database server, which in our case is CST, US.

I get the part where its appending the fractional seconds as mentioned in this link [ResultSet.getString(Date) differs based on driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840542/resultset-getstringdate-differs-based-on-driver)

The problem is that we don't need a daylight saving adjusted time, but need the time that was initially inserted.  However, using other ways of fetching the date such as resultSet.getDate(), resultSet.getTimeStamp() is also returning the DST adjusted time.

We found that the only way out is to change the type of the date column to TIMESTAMP and the problem is resolved.

Has anyone encountered this problem with oracle 12c(ojdbc7) driver?

If yes, is there a better way of resolving it?  I really want to avoid changing the data type of the existing columns to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: In the release notes for 12.1.0.1 ojdbc7.jar there is this fix listed. 
9869716    PRINTING STRING VALUE OF TIMESTAMPTZ IS SENSITIVE TO DEFAULT TIMEZONE  Conversion of TIMESTAMPTZ to a string can produce wrong results.

Comment: 12.1.0.2 release notes has fix 9785135  DST CONVERSION NOT CORRECT USING JDBC 11G TIMESTAMPTZ  Wrong TIMESTAMPTZ value could be constructed.

Perhaps the 11.2.0.3.0 driver implementation was considered a bug.

Comment: If you want to end up with a string, why aren't you using `to_char()` so you know how it will be formatted? Presumably that would also avoid this issue as the driver never sees the date. If you want it as a date you could cast it to timestamp rather than change the column type, but that's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thanks Brian. So does this mean resultSet.getString(DATE COLUMN) will internally convert this to TIMESTAMP with timezone and 11.2.0.3 had an incorrect fix, which is now fixed in 12.1.0.2.  So should we change the type of the column to TIMESTAMP then, if we don't want a DST adjusted time?

Comment: Why are you using `getString()` in the first place? If that is a `date` or `timestamp` column you should be using `getTimestamp()`

Comment: You can also cast the `ResultSet` to an `OracleResultSet` and then use `getTIMESTAMPLTZ()` or `getTIMESTAMPTZ()` which returns an `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPLTZ` or an `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` which should contain the correct value

Comment: its a DATE column, and if I used getDate() its returning DST adjusted time in case we enter a date with time which falls in the interval when DST starts. getString was used to get around this problem in ojdbc6, but this doesn't seem to work with ojdbc7 now.   From the above response I am not able to figure out if Oracle fixed an inherent bug that was there in ojdbc6 with the new release of ojdbc7.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. I was using the `rs.getString(index)` to avoid daylight saving adjustment for `Date` type, but with ojdbc7, `rs.getString(index)` is also adjusting the time for daylight saving.